# Must template parameters be types?

Tags: c++, templates

In the Bjarne Stroustrup C++ Book (chapter 13, page 331), it said that "a template parameter can be used in the definition of subsequent template parameter". And it gives the following code:

```
template<class T, T def_val> class Cont{ /* ... */ }
```

Can anyone provide an example of how to use this template. For example, how to initialize an object of Cont? It look to me that "def_val" is not a type argument, and should not be placed in <>. Am I wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: you should know that this is valid only if T is an integral type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Cont<int, 6> cnt;
//        ^ as long as this is of type T (in this case int)
// def_val will be of type int and have a value of 6
```

Template parameters aren't required to be types.

This only works when `T` is an integral type (`int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `char` etc but not `float`, `std::string`, `const char*`, etc), as @Riga mentioned in his/her comment.

Answer (score 6):

`def_val` is a value argument. An instantiation could look like this:

```
Cont<int, 1> foo;
```

An interesting case where this is useful is when you want to have a pointer to a class-member as template paremeter:

```
template<class C, int C::*P>
void foo(C * instance);
```

This enables `foo` to be instantiated with a pointer to a member of type `int` of any class.

Comment: Although I think the correct term is `non-type template parameter`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how to instantiate the above:

```
template<class T, T def_val> class Cont{ /* ... */ };

int main()
{
    Cont<int,42> c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`T def_val` is an object of type `T` (which was previously passed). It could be used to initialize items in the container, for example. To use, it would look something like:

```
Object init(0);
Cont<Object, init> cont;
```

*(psuedo-code; `Object` must obviously be a type that's legal to use in this manner)*

That then uses the second template parameter. It's included in the template because it has a templated type; `def_val` must be of type `T` and must be passed when the object is created.

Comment: I don't know if this works.  Maybe if Object's constructor is constexpr?